Prevent Playwright form considering @ char as tag in a specific test
I have the following test:
const specialChars = `#@<`;

for (let specialChar of specialChars) {
  if (specialChar === "@") specialChar = `\@`;
  test(`search special character: "${specialChar}"`, async ({ page }) => {
    // test content
  });
}

The problem is that Playwright consider the ' that closes the test name as tag.

I've tried to add \ before the @ like that, but it didn't help:
if (specialChar === "@") specialChar = `\@`;

Is there any way to prevent that?

test("This is a literal character @ ")

Or may be just do't use it in test title.

Has to... this is the only way to make the test name unique and understandable

I've found a solution using Unicode value \u{ff20} (original value u+ff20) like so:
const specialChars = `#\u{ff20}<`;
for (let specialChar of specialChars) {
  test(`search special character: "${specialChar}"`, async ({ page }) => {
   // test content
  });
}


